# Video streaming using ffmpeg with VLC

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, vlc

I am trying to stream a video called "bbb.mp4" with ffmpeg and visualize it with VLC.

On the OS X Terminal, I do the following:

`ffmpeg -re -i bbb.mp4 -an -c:v copy -f mpegts udp://@127.0.0.1:2222`

I am video streaming it on the IP address 127.0.0.1 using the port 2222. Once I run this, it shows that it is streaming the video:

[image]

But when I visualize it using VLC by going File > Open Network... > Network:

[image]

I cannot see anything, even though the code is running in the Terminal:

[image]

It does not open. Do you know if I am doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding packet_size at the end. For example:

```
ffmpeg -re -i bbb.mp4 -an -c:v copy -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:2222?pkt_size=1316
```

And of course, at VLC:

```
udp://127.0.0.1:2222?pkt_size=1316
```